# Flex remote object to java class instantion and multithreading

Tags: java, apache-flex

After reading this very same topic about Java Servlets:

[How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

I started looking for documentation about how this works for LCDS or Blaze remote objects on flex without any luck so far...

so, does any one knows about good documentation or its experienced enough to answer this?

I'm currently using flash builder 4.6, ADEP Data Services for Java EE 4.6 and JBoss 7.1.

Edit: I'm gonna specify some of my doubts on remote objects:

If the scope is application, is the class instanced on application start up like java servlets?, whats the concurrency behavior on different scopes?, are request scope objects created and destroyed on each call?, what about static members?.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is limited, and with GraniteDS (which from my understanding is very similar to BlazeDS in how it works ).  AMF calls hit a servlet (which I think is called MessageBrokerServlet).  This servlet will call the configured service.  The AMF servlet works like any other servlet, and follows the same life cycle.  Your service classes do not follow this life cycle, and are by default managed by BlazeDS.  You can read more about the scope of the destination (the services exposed by BlazeDS) [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=rpc_remoteobject_3.html).  You can configure one of three scope(request scope, the application scope, or the session scope )Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i already knew about MessageBrokerServlet, but i have no idea about how it works, and is something i have been trying to figure out, like when people say "if MessageBrokerServlet/amf throws a 404 error, then there is something wrong" but then what?, sometimes servlets don't get deployed, and i cant find any documentation about that neither...

Comment: Well, if the servlet doesn't get deployed, you'll see an error in your container log with info.  The AMF servlet is not that complicated, and if it has error, it should also be displayed in the log, unless you swallow the exception or have logging turned off. If you have an specific case, then by all means post it.